# use a standalone app.blade for a page set in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a 9 pages set with restricted access in the app (needs to be logged in). These pages cannot use the default `app.blade.php` because they have a different panel than the default panel. I created a layout folder where the pages are, but laravel uses both `app.blade.php` instead of just the one that I need, it ends up damaging the panel of these pages because both use the same css.

I only need to use the `app.blade.php` from that folder.

I tried to hide the other panel like this: `.not-as-home {display: none;}` but still breaks the other panel because the other `app.blade.php` is still loading

Both `app.blade.php` files have the same content, the difference is in the content of the `auth.blade.php` and `sidebar.blade.php` views that load the panel html, one loads the top menu and the other in the sidebar.

index: `@extends('company.clients.layouts.app')`

app.blade.php (2)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        @stack('seo') 
        @stack('styles')
    </head>
    <body>
        @auth()
            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                @csrf
            </form>
            @include('company.clients.layouts.navbars.sidebar')
        @endauth

        <div class ="main-content">
            @include('company.clients.layouts.navbars.navbar')
            @yield('content')
        </div>

        @guest()
            @include('company.clients.layouts.footers.guest')
        @endguest

        @stack('js')
    </body>
</html>
```

That's it, the code says more than words, I need to show the contents of `company.clients.layouts.navbar.auth.blade.php` and not `layouts.navbar.auth.blade.php` as it does.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking, could you add the other files please ?

Comment: the files are very large and it's just html, it doesn't influence anything, the simple question is there is folder A and folder B, folder B needs its own app.blade.php, but when trying to use app.blade from folder B, laravel also loads app.blade.php from folder A, breaking the code, how do I solve this?

Comment: understand folder A as app.blade.php present in view / layouts and folder B as app.blade.php present in view / company / clients / layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to create a system in which there are different types of users is to create 2 separate folders, where each folder will have its app.blade.php, another alternative is to include the sidbar and navbar in the page view.

You can do this:

**app.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
            @yield('nav')
            @yield('content')
            @yield('footer')
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```